# HTML5 canvas gradients in LWC are all black

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, developer, html5, lwc-dom

I'm trying to create a HTML5 canvas with a simple gradient in LWC. However, it's all black. The code I'm trying is almost completely copied from W3C (except it's adjusted for LWC).

HTML

```html
<template>
    <div class="chart" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

JS

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class CanvasTest extends LightningElement {
    rendered = false;

    renderedCallback() {
      if (this.rendered) {
        return;
      }
      this.rendered = true;

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.template.querySelector('div.chart').appendChild(canvas);
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      // Create gradient
      const grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
      grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
      grd.addColorStop(1, 'white');

      // Fill with gradient
      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);
    }
}
```

I've tried a few non-gradient canvas functionalities and everything seems ok, but I can't get gradients to work at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks to work in the playground https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/b5jvnmFY1/1/edit

Comment: Its not working when tried in org

Comment: Looks like `fillStyle` is defaulting to `#000000` in an org

Comment: Looks like `createLinearGradient` might not be available in the Locker Service 

https://twitter.com/GrayJustise/status/1172192318461366272?s=20